# Why is the frame bundle of the Möbius strip the Z2 bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

In the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_bundle#Definition_and_construction) figure it says "The frame bundle $\mathcal{F}(E)$ of the Möbius strip $E$ is a non-trivial principal $\mathbb {Z} /2\mathbb{Z}$-bundle over the circle."

Shouldn't the frame bundle of the Möbius strip has $GL(1,R)$ as its fiber? Why is the fiber the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ group? What is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ anyway?

Comment: That part of the wiki article strikes me as wrong and the picture is misleading, too. It depicts a Möbius strip with boundary, but the total space of the Möbius bundle over $S^1$ is a Möbius strip without boundary. Furthermore, the claim is indeed wrong. The non-trivial principal $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-bundle over $S^1$ arises as the *orthonormal* frame bundle of the Möbius bundle wrt the natural bundle metric. The frame bundle can be obtained by taking the total space $\times\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I understood the *orthonormal* frame bundle part. What is the notation $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$? Is it just $\mathbb{Z}_2$? I don't quite follow your last sentence: which total space?

Comment: As it seems you suspect, $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ is a quotient group, a particular avatar of the group of order $2$. It's more natural here to view orthonormal frames in the fibres as elements of the _multiplicative_ group $O(1) = \{1, -1\}$. (Some people use $\mathbf{Z}_{2}$ to connote the group of $2$-adic integers; perhaps the wiki author was avoiding that potential ambiguity.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Yes, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is just another notation of $\mathbb{Z}_2$.